# Cross validation error dependency?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, cross-validation

Let's say we are running CV with K folds. Can you give an intuitive explanation on why the errors per fold are dependent? I was asked this and after thinking about it I kind of see it but need some good examples or intuition to finish understanding.

Can we say that the folds are independent but the errors are dependent?

This question may be too basic but need some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be good to define clearly what exactly "error" should mean in this discussion: Whether "error" is a property of the (surrogate) model or whether it means the deviation for a given single prediction from the truth/reference value. However:

---

**Short answer**: 
Yes, the errors should be dependent, and the folds should be independent, or:

The surrogate models *should* be dependent among each other. The test cases for each surrogate model may be independent, but each test set should be independent from *its* surrogate model (that's why the folds need to be independent).

---

**Long answer**: 
Cross validation assumes that all of the surrogate models are equivalent (or at least sufficiently similar) to the model trained on the whole data set - that's why we can use the test results for a number of surrogate models as surrogate (or estimate or approximation) for the test results of the whole-data-model. This causes a (very much wanted!) dependence of the error estimates.

If this assumption is valid each of the models in question should yield the same prediction for the same input. (If this assumption does not hold, the models are unstable, and not useful for prediction.)
This makes the error as property of the surrogate models at least correlated, if not highly correlated to practically equal. The correlation of the measured/observed errors of the surrogate models may be lower. If only a few cases are tested for each model, there may be considerable variance around the mean error for the surrogate model in question.

Correlation for errors of a single predictions will depend on correlation of the mean error for the surrogate models in question (high, according to the assumption) as well as on the (in)dependence between the test cases. Typically, one tries to get independent cases, though that is not always the case: Independence for cross validation usually refers to the test data of one surrogate model and that surrogate model not being dependent. However, there may be dependence within the test data for one surrogate model.
As an example, I work with medical data where we have repeated measurements of the same patient. These repeated measurements are not independent, so I take care to do the cross validation folds by patient to get independence between each model and its test data. But I both train and test including the repeated measurements, so the test results within each surrogate model's test do have dependence.